# How to avoid similar route in iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Sorry for the bad English.

I have a tabs with four tab, each has a route

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li role="presentation"><a href="{{pathFor 'menu.tab1'">tab1</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="{{pathFor 'menu.tab2'">tab2</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="{{pathFor 'menu.tab3'">tab3</a></li>
 <li role="presentation"><a href="{{pathFor 'menu.tab4'">tab4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And route.js

```
this.route('/menu/tab1', {
  name: 'menu.tab1',
  template: 'MenuTab1',
});         
this.route('/menu/tab2', {
  name: 'menu.tab2',
  template: 'MenuTab2',
});
this.route('/menu/tab3', {
  name: 'menu.tab3',
  template: 'MenuTab3',
});
this.route('/menu/tab4', {
  name: 'menu.tab4',
  template: 'MenuTab4',
});
```

Can I simplify these similar code?

Comment: If you use tabs, shouldn't they have preloaded content panes underneath them? It should be a [bootstrap logic](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), not an iron router one.

Comment: Apart from this, why not use loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by @Petr, you can refactor your code to use arrays.

```
var tabs = [{
  label: "tab1",
  route: {
    path: "/menu/tab1",
    name: "menu.tab1",
    template: "MenuTab1"
  }
},{
  [...]
}];

tabs.forEach(function(tab){
  var route = tab.route;
  Router.route(route.path,{
    name: route.name,
    template: route.template
  });
});

Template.tabs.helpers({
  tabs: tabs
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    {{#each tabs}}
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="{{pathFor route.name}}">label</a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

If your tabs follow an exact pattern regarding naming scheme, you could even fo further :

```
var tabs = [{
  id: "tab1",
  label: "Tab 1"
},{
  [...]
}];

tabs = tabs.map(function(tab){
  function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }
  //
  return {
    label: tab.label,
    route: {
      path: "/menu/" + tab.id,
      name: "menu." + tab.id,
      template: "Menu" + capitalizeFirstLetter(tab.id)
    }
  };
});
```